# typescript how to declare class with a method with a parameter of type string that is property name of derived class of specific type

Tags: typescript, typescript-declarations

I have a base class with a method callable from derived classes where you supply one of the derived property names that must be of a specific type.  The property value is then operated on.  I want to be able to specify this specific type.  ( keyof obviously is not sufficient )

Is it possible to type this ?

This does not work

```
type PropertyNamesOfType<T extends {},TPropertyType> = {
 [P in keyof T]: TPropertyType extends T[P] ? P : never
}[keyof T]

declare class TypeUsingBoolPropertyOfDerived{
  withArgKeyOfTypeBoolean<E extends PropertyNamesOfType<this, boolean>>(arg:E):void;
}

class Test extends TypeUsingBoolPropertyOfDerived{
  boolProp:boolean
  stringProp:string
  try(): void {
   this.withArgKeyOfTypeBoolean('boolProp');
   //Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PropertyNamesOfType<this, boolean>'.
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is that polymorphic `this` behaves like a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type parameter, and inside the implementation of `Test`, `this` is an as-yet-unspecified/unresolved type parameter, and the compiler can't verify much about it. (There are some GitHub issues that mention this, at least in passing; see [microsoft/TypeScript#41495](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41495), [microsoft/TypeScript#41181](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41181))

*Outside* `Test`, where you are just *using* an instance of `Test` instead of implementing it, the compiler will substitute `Test` for `this` and all will behave as expected, like

```
new Test().withArgKeyOfTypeBoolean("boolProp"); // okay
```

That leads to a possible workaround: inside `try()`, first assign the (generic-like) `this` to the (specific) `Test`, and then call `withArgKeyOfTypeBoolean()` on *that*:

```
try(): void {
    const thisTest: Test = this;
    thisTest.withArgKeyOfTypeBoolean('boolProp'); // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTge0nUA5AhgWwgZwPIBmAKuBADxFQQAewEAdgCY5QDeAvgDRRHxIQoQJSAD4oAXjYAoKLKgBtGFACW9KAGsIIBAR4BdAFw8+yUMOg06TFkUV6oAflhQj9CADcBU9vM3bdRHpSUowQAMYANuhw0JHoODakAKo4qgDmAEIICBEmAqCEACICyp6M0nJQAO7KwAAWAIJwaQDSWoTmWTkQ6PRkAKJUtAzMsIimIBjY+MSkZPXKONwARtkRPfQiIgAU0WlG-QCURu4IyowA3N7BcQk8uMBDVqPmKeldueP5IEUlZRVyVY5ExGIHrXoyOQ4YBwdIgqDQ2H0NKQ2QwkDbY5QU7nAGVWRhBD0aFQBY4IgPIwUkmSMlXfFyMnU4AAOhq9SarXas0gHw22wA5GCTALDhcoAB6CVQBDqdAgVFQdjXKRuKr3aGYtm1RrNNo-HkQPm9bYAImF41NYqAA)